# Get all shopify products filtered by a Tag using Liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

Is it possible to query all products in shopify by a tag (or set of tags) using Liquid.

I thought I had it by looping through collections.all.products and then filtering in the loop but then realised that the collection was limited to a page size of 50.

Comment: The maximum limit for pagination is 1000, not 50.

Comment: Doesn't seem to return 1000 in a liquid template from what I can see. Is there an optional parameter to specify it? Either way, you cant seem to query by a tag, only by a collection name.

Comment: `{% paginate <array> by 1000 %}{% for .......... ... endfor %}{% endpaginate %}`

Answer (score 3):

If it meant to be displayed in frontend, Shopify does not support the paginate hack quoted by Hymnz above.

However, even if query is limited to 50 products, you may clearly make your query and then use pagination.Something like this may work to filter products list:

```
{% for product in collections.all.products %}
{% if product.tags contains 'mytag' %}
Do something
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I'm sorry. The hack does work. In fact, the maximum recursive processing can take upto 40,000 loops in Shopify liquid. A for loop by default it 50 entries only.

Comment: Hi! I did not say it was not working ;).But that is a non sense for frontend display (performance) and not recommended by Shopify. 
Then, it only works if you use pagination trick.

Comment: So how should you pull more than 50 unless you are using the API? The OP was asking using liquid code only no?